# Multiple Postgres schema issue when using pandas to_sql with SQL Alchemy core

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am exporting a pandas df to postgres using the SA core. Here is the basic script:

```
engine = db.create_engine(f'postgresql://data-catalogue:{dbpwd}@postgres-data-catalogue-dev/data-catalogue')

metadata = db.MetaData(schema="abn")  

eshc_underlyers = db.Table('eshc_underlyers', metadata,
        db.Column('description', db.String),
        db.Column('isin', db.String),
        db.Column('ul_product', db.String, primary_key=True),
        db.Column('reference_product', db.String),
        db.Column('haircut_base', db.String, primary_key=True),
        db.Column('base_cur',db.String),
        db.Column('business_date', db.DateTime, primary_key=True),
        db.Column('account', db.String, primary_key=True),
       )
    
metadata.create_all(engine)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    strUlDf.to_sql(name='eshc_underlyers', con=conn , if_exists='append', index = False)
```

When this runs it creates both an "abn" schema and a "public" schema, but the public one is not needed. Also when interrogating the DB the "abn" schema shows the correct composite key being applied, but the "public" schema has none applied at all.  The effect of this is that I can run this same script over and over and it will ignore the constraints and allow the duplicates to load into the public schema. At the same time select * from abn.eshc_underlyers returns mothing.  Alternatively if I remove schema="abn" the public default schema works correctly and constraints are observed, but ofc this is not what I need.

Not an expert in python or postgres so feeling my way a little here.

Answer (score 0):

ok, figured this out.  You have to pass the schema into BOTH the Metadata() statement AND the to_sql statement. In this case the public schema is not created at all.